# Javascript: How to write a function that accepts different number of parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

In JS (with Flow) How to define a function and call it with different number of parameters

Say I have a function with parameters typed with flow

```
function fun(
  name: string,
  age?: string,
  gender: string,
  metaData?: {
    hobby: ?string,
    lifeGoal: ?string,
  }
): void {
  // do something
}
```

This is how I want to call them, in two ways:

```
fun('Jimmy', '30', 'male', {hobby: 'ride bike', lifeGoal: 'beat Zerg'});
```

```
fun('Kerri', 'female', {hobby: 'transform', lifeGoal: 'beat Terran'});
```

If I don't want to put 'age' into 'metaData', how do I make sure 'female' is mapped to 'gender' instead of 'age' since they are both string type.

Comment: What about using null as second parameter when no age should be set?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "overloading" and isn't a feature of javascript. You can fake it by allowing your function to accept an object as a parameter and you can stuff whatever you want in that object. See below for example:

```
function foo(a, b, opts) {
  // ...
  if (opts['test']) { } //if test param exists, do something.. 
}


foo(1, 2, {"method":"add"});
foo(3, 4, {"test":"equals", "bar":"tree"});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not support named arguments like say Python does.

[babel-plugin-named-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-named-params) makes that if you can rely on transpiling(and is fine with its caveats):

```
func(name = 'Kerri', gender = 'gemale'
```

Otherwise you can either pass `undefined` for values that are not meant to be passed

```
fun('Kerri', undefined, 'female' ...
```

Or using large object where not every property is expected to be present. But you say you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

As previous posters mentioned, there is no overloading in JS.  You can, however, make another function that encapsulates the original and always passes null to age.

### New Function

```
function noAgefun(
  name: string,
  gender: string,
  metaData?: {
    hobby: ?string,
    lifeGoal: ?string,
  }
): void {
   fun(name, null, gender, metaData);
}
```

### Original Function

```
function fun(
  name: string,
  age?: string,
  gender: string,
  metaData?: {
    hobby: ?string,
    lifeGoal: ?string,
  }
): void {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a single object instead:

```
    function fun(value : {
      name: string,
      age?: string,
      gender: string,
      metaData?: {
        hobby: ?string,
        lifeGoal: ?string,
      }
    }): void {
      // do something
    }
```

So turn all the arguments into a single object.

Then you're examples just work better:

```
fun({name: 'Jimmy', age: '30', gender:'male', metadata: {hobby: 'ride bike', lifeGoal: 'beat Zerg'}});

fun({name: 'Kerri', gender:'female', metadata:{hobby: 'transform', lifeGoal: 'beat Terran'}});
```

Flow Object Types: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/